# Client side validation in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: jquery, validation, attributes, client, asp.net-core

I am having trouble getting client side validation to work in ASP.NET Core MVC. I've googled and applied the example from here (http://www.discuzfeed.com/code/lotooslo-mvc-6-client-side-validation-for-custom-attribute.html) but no luck.

Here is my code

**Attribute**

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = false)]
public sealed class CannotBeRedAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientModelValidator
{  
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        var message = value as string;
        return false;
        //return message?.ToLower() == "red";
    }

    public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(
        ClientModelValidationContext context)
    { 
        yield return new ModelClientValidationRule(
            "cannotbered",
            FormatErrorMessage(ErrorMessage));
    }
}
```

**View Model**

```
    [CannotBeRed(ErrorMessage = "Not red!")]
    public string SelectedCompanyIds { get; set; }
```

**View**

```
<input type="hidden" name="test" class="form-control"     id="selectCompanyIdControl" data-bind="value: SelectedReportCompanyIds" asp-    for="SelectedCompanyIds" />

 @<script type="text/javascript">
    require(['jquery', 'knockout-es5', 'jquery-validation', 'jquery-validation-unobtrusive', 'pubsubjs', 'ReportEditViewModel'], function(jquery, knockout, jQueryVal, jQueryValUnobtrusive, pubsub, vm) {


        jquery(document).ready(function () {  

            jquery.validator.addMethod("cannotbered",
                function (value, element, parameters) {
                    alert("READ");
                    return value.toLowerCase() !== "red";
                });

            jquery.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add('cannotbered', [], function (options) {
                alert("ADAPATER");
                options.rules.cannotbered = {};
                options.messages['cannotbered'] = options.message;
            });
```

Ignore fact that brackets not closed correctly in view, there are other JS parts to do with knockout which not copying here as not relevant.

The `GetClientValidationRules` method is being hit, but the alerts in the JS are not.  Just for info, when run developer tools in chrome or IE I can see that the jquery validation and unobtrusive libraries are loaded, and that there are no console errors.  The validation tag seems to be ok on the input box....

```
<input type="hidden" name="test" class="form-control" id="selectCompanyIdControl" data-bind="value: SelectedReportCompanyIds" data-val="true" data-val-cannotbered="Not red!" value="" />
```

So I think I'm just missing one step, but cant think what it could be.  Any pointers?

Comment: Did you ever worked this out? I am hitting the same issue...

Comment: Hi, I'm afraid not, had to abandon it and never got back to it.  Please post here if have a solution.  Thanks

Comment: If you need custom validation on the client-side, maybe this framework can help you: [Dryv - DRY Validation for ASP.NET Core](https://dryv-lib.net). Disclaimer: I am the author.

You may have a look into the source code on GitGub if you want to see the integration with ASP.NET and\or jQuery validation.